# How can I write data to BigQuery with Spark SQL?

Tags: apache-spark-sql, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataproc

We are using Google Dataproc cluster and `spark-sql` shell.
And able to create a table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE table_bq
USING bigquery
OPTIONS (
  project 'project',
  dataset 'dataset',
  table 'bq_table'
  );
```

This connects to BigQuery for all query purposes, however, when we try to do

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE table_bq SELECT ....;
```

It fails with error:

> ) does not allow insertion.;;

Any pointers on how can we load data into BigQuery from spark-sql ?
Note: I have seen example of writing data to BigQuery with spark with dataframe, however my question is there anyway to do with spark-sql?

Comment: How did you add the BQ connector to the cluster or your job? Could you show the command or code?

Comment: @Dagang Following command: "spark-sql --jars gs://spark-lib/bigquery/spark-bigquery-latest_2.12.jar"